# How does AngularJS work with JS minifiers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How does dependency injection in AngularJS actually work?

Yeah, I read a lot of stuff and I know how to **use** it.

Suppose that we have the following controller:

```
app.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$location', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $location) { /* ... */ }]);
```

I know that we should use pass an array to be able to use JS minifiers, so Angular will know real names of dependencies anyway.

Suppose that we actually use JS minifier and the `$scope` was traslated to `$s`. How will Angular know that this `$s` is actually a `$scope` so it should have the same interface as described in the `$scope`'s documentation?

Comment: I believe the reason is because Angular knows the $location parameter can be supplied as an argument which allows the global $scope variable to provide the necessary context in minified code.

Comment: @Benjamin Dean Sorry, I don't get it. Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: Nikki answered the technical reason.  The easiest way to think about minification of code is this: replace all the long variable and function names with the shortest, non-human readable identifiers as possible. Minifiers don't really change the structure of your code...they just make the verbiage smaller (much like the English language uses acronyms to shorten long-phrases). This reduces the file size of your code which makes transferring the file(s) over the network faster....get it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Minification process makes all names and parameters of function shorter to reduce the weight of files. So once your controller getting minified he will looks like this:

`function(a, b, c, d) { /* ... */ }]);`

But if you are using `$inject`, or pass array of injections with function, it will let your function know which exactly service should be injected to each of parameter into your controller.

```
app.controller('LoginCtrl', [
'$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$location', 
function(a, b, c, d) { /* ... */ }]);
```

So once it will be minified angular will still the names of services which should be injected and position number(index of element in array) each of them which is linked to index of parameter in controller function. So, as we see, **order matters**.

Comment: Are you sure? I thought that we can reorder parameters of such functions w/o having to update the elements in the array

Comment: Take a look at the documentation -- https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di. It says that "the ordering of the values in the $inject array must match the ordering of the parameters in MyController" only for the "$inject Property Annotation". For the "Inline Array Annotation" it just says "take care to keep the annotation array in sync with the parameters in the function declaration". I thought that it means that we just have to pass the same number of arguments as we have in an array

Comment: @FrozenHeart Take care to **keep** *the annotation array* **in sync** *with the parameters in the function declaration.*

Comment: Could you please answer the related question, please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39543499/how-to-inject-dependencies-for-standalone-functions

Comment: @FrozenHeart, just thinking about simple js, I don't understand how it will link injections to parameters without strict order. We can check it experimentally , but I am sure 90 % that it matters :)

Comment: @FrozenHeart, sure